# Novel where moon is dead because of time warp

Tags: story-identification, space-exploration, moon

An old science fiction novel, originally published or reprinted in paperback in the 1960s, in the English language.

The first expedition to the moon eventually discovers that the reason why it is dead is because it is in a time warp that speeds up time many times and thus is billions of years older than the Earth.

At the end, the time warp is accelerated many times and the entire moon disintegrates.

I don't remember, but I think there might be a machine that speeds up time on the moon and because of some conflict or danger the Earth explorers turn it up several times which causes the whole moon to  disintegrate.

Doing so would seem to kill the explorers with rapid aging but maybe they were immune for some reason.  And I don't remember what sort of threat or danger could exist on a moon that was dead and unchanging.

Comment: Is there any explanation for the moon being in a time warp? Natural phenomenon or advanced alien technology? The result of an ancient war fought by the indigenous inhabitants?

Comment: I don't remember.  It is possible that there is a machine that speeds up time on the moon, and maybe because of some problem or danger the heroes have to increase the power setting.  Though that should make them die of old age too, and I don't know what danger there could be on a dead world where nothing ever happens.